# Overriding HashCode() in Java with double values

Tags: java

I know this is asked a lot, and I don't know if I quite understand hash codes, but it's supposed to be the address and so how do I fix my particular example? If my understanding is correct, I have doubles in my class, but I can't add them to the hash code, because of

```
possible loss of precision
found   : double
required: int
   return this.area();
```

Here is my `Shape` class:

```
abstract class Shape implements Comparable<Shape>
{ 
    abstract double area(); 


    public int compareTo(Shape sh){
        return Double.compare(this.area(),sh.area());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.area();     
    }

    public boolean equals(Shape sh) {
        if ( sh instanceof Shape && this.area()==sh.area() ) {
            return true;         
        } else  {
            return false ;
        }
    }
}
```

Is `area()` the only value I need to worry about in `hashCode()?`

Comment: The behaviour of hashCode should match that of equals such that if two objects are considered equal using `equals` then the hashCode of two objects should be the same. If you are only using the area of a shape to determine if it is equal, then you can just return the area for the hashCode.

Comment: `Shape` is an abstract class. Do you want two shapes of the same area to be equal even if they are different shapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the example of hashCode in Double class :

```
public int hashCode() {
    long bits = doubleToLongBits(value);
    return (int)(bits ^ (bits >>> 32));
}
```

This would avoid the loss of precision caused by simply casting the double to int.

If the area is the only property that determines the hashCode, you can use the exact same code, replacing `value` with `area`.

However, I'm not sure `area` is a good candidate for hashCode calculation, since it is itself calculated from properties of the sub-classes of Shape. You should probably implement hashCode in each sub-class of Shape based on the specific properties of that sub-class.

Comment: @user4254704 I'm assuming the area is calculated using properties of sub-classes of Shape. See my edit.

Comment: @user4254704 It's a static method of Double class. Try Double.doubletolongbits

Comment: what if I have multiple values

Comment: @user4254704 If you are using Java 7 or higher, you can use [Objects.hash(Object... values)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29) to hash multiple values.

Comment: I get the error cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Objects

Comment: @user4254704 You have to import java.util.Objects, but it only exists since Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just add the numbers together to produce a hash code; that's very likely to get duplicate hash codes for unequal objects close together. Instead, I recommend using either the `Objects.hash` method from the standard Java API or the more expressive and efficient `HashCodeBuilder` from Apache Commons-Lang. You should include in the `hashCode` calculation exactly the same fields that you use to determine `equals`.

Of course, as @khelwood pointed out, you very likely *don't* want to implement `equals` and `hashCode` on this abstract object, since a 1x4 rectangle and a 2x2 rectangle probably aren't equal. Instead, you can re-declare those methods as `abstract` on `Shape` to force subclasses to implement them:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know what you're saying, I just don't know how to recognize two different shapes are equal

Comment: @user4254704 You'll have to figure out what the rules for that are. Most objects are only equal to other objects of the exact same class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return Double.valueOf(this.area()).hashCode();
}
```

-- Edition: corrected valueOf method name. Thank you @user4254704.